# How to bestway to select data from immutable database?

Tags: mysql, sql

i've data like this.
[image]

table out_trans, with column:

```
id, trans_no, status, amount, net, net_commission, ddp, country_id, merchant_id, payment_channel_id, is_test, type, created_at, updated_at
```

if i using this query the result will be retrieve all data but still have a duplicate trans_no:

```sql
select * from out_trans
```

i want to, if i select this table, will be retrive without duplicate data.if the trans_no is more than one then retrieve the latest data based on the last updated from updated_at column

Comment: Please no pictures and a more clear description of what you want as result. 
So I can only imagin, that `select * from table_name where trans_no = whatYouWant order by updated_at desc limit 1;` may be a solution.

Comment: i've update the description @h.m.i.13

Comment: Please define what a "duplicate" is.  Please provide data as *text tables* or at least in a format that does not require a magnifying glass to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT MAX(updated_at), id, trans_no, status, amount, net, net_commission, ddp, country_id, merchant_id, payment_channel_id, is_test, type, created_at
FROM table name
GROUP BY trans_no, id, status, amount, net, net_commission, ddp, country_id, merchant_id, payment_channel_id, is_test, type, created_at
```

Comment: Because of different `status` I think this will give more than one row per `trans_no`

Comment: yes, correct.
do u have any idea? @h.m.i.13

Comment: I have no mysql to the hand and not you data (only the picture) but I think one of the following should work: 
`select * from out_trans a where a.updated_at in (select max(b.updated_at) from out_trans b where b.trans_no = a.trans_no);` (probably very slow)
or 
`select * from out_trans 
where (trans_no, updated_at) in (select trans_no, max(updated_at) from out_trans group by trans_no);`